Moving and organizing files with find
I have a folder on a Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64 Server used as a NAS/Homelab server with a lot of files from a surveillance camera.
MDAlarm_20240301-091804.jpg
...
MDAlarm_20240316-153813.jpg
MDAlarm_20240327-183713.jpg

If I try to move the files with (eg) mv snap/*.jpg /path/to/dest/2024/03 I get

-bash: /usr/bin/mv: Argument list too long


I was thinking that something like this answer find snap -name '*202403??-??????.jpg' -exec mv -t /path/to/dest/2024/03 {} + would work, but is there a "one liner" to create appropriate folders for year and month?
I am moving them to a samba share to review and sort the pictures

First of all, you don't strictly need to have the year and month folders. You can move them all with find:
find snap -name '*202403??-??????.jpg' -exec mv -t /path/to/dest {} +

Now, if you need them arranged by date, and if we can assume that all of your files are as you show, MDAlarm_, then the date, then a - and the time followe by .jpg, with no whitespace or other odd characters, you could do something like this:
outDir=/some/existing/directory
find snap -type f -name '*202403??-??????.jpg' | 
while read filename; do
  date=$(awk -F'[-_]' '{print $2}' <<<"$filename")
  read year month day < <(perl -pe 's/(....)(..)(..)/$1 $2 $3/' <<<"$date") 
  target="$outDir/$year/$month/$day"
  mkdir -p -- "$target" &&
     mv -- "$filename" "$target"
done

Note that this also assumes that there are no - or _ characters anywhere in the path before the file name. So if you try this and you have things like snap/some-dir/MDAlarm_20240301-091804.jpg, it will fail.
The approach is relatively simple: we run the find command, then parse the output. First, we use awk with a field delimiter of - or _ on the filename to get the date. If your files are always like MDAlarm_20240301-whatever, then the second field as defined by _ and - will be 20240301, the date. So date gets 20240301 as the value.
This is then passed through a perl substitution that inserts a space after the first 4 characters, another after the next two and one more after the next two. So 20240301 becomes  2024 03 01 and this is fed to read which will save 2024 as $year, 03 as $month and 01 as $day (I am assuming standard dates here, if you are using American style, change the order of those variable names).
We then create a $target variable to hold the name of the directory we want to create, using the outDir we defined in the beginning as the parent directory udner which the others will be created, and in the last step, assuming the mkdir -p was successful (it will be, even if the directory already exists, but not if it cannot access the target), we copy the files over.

actually there is an underscore in the path - but I assume I can circumvent that with ln :   /home/cam001/FI9826W_001122DDFDBD/snap

I assume also that I can just substitute find snap -type f -name '*202403??-??????.jpg' with find snap -type f -name '*.jpg' ?

@JoSSte terdon is referring to the results of the find containing an underscore in the directory/path; in your case your find is going to generate output of the form snap/MDAlarm_20240301-091804.jpg, so no undescore in the directory/path; now, if you were sitting in /home/cam001/ and ran find . -name '*jpg' then you'd get results like FI9826W_001122DDFDBD/snap/MDAlarm_20240301-091804.jpg and in this case you would need to address terndon's comment re: directory/path containing underscores

What markp-fuso said, @JoSSte. As for '*.jpg', sure, if you want to process all jpg files, then yes, absolutely. I only used your pattern because I assumed that's what you needed. If the files are all in a single directory, you can even remove find entirely and go for for file in *jpg; do ... done.
